# How can I run a large gremlin script in rexster console?

Tags: java, groovy, orientdb, gremlin, rexster

I'm using Orientdb and rexster.

I have a rather large script file which includes vertices and edges upserts. when I try to run my script like:
rexster-console.sh  -rh localhost -rp 8984 -e /tmp/script

I get the following error:

```
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain execute
WARNING: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.client.RexProClientConnection$1.handleRead(RexProClientConnection.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:815)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:567)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

when I run the script again I get this:

```
An error occurred while processing the script for language [groovy]. All transactions across all          graphs in the session have been concluded with failure: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 698951 in class file Script12
closing session with Rexster [localhost:8984]--> done
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: is that error on the client or server?

Comment: @stephenmallette I get it when I try to run the script file with rexster-console in terminal. so I assume it's the client.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a problem and fix in relation to this error:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/issues/374

The fix was implemented, but it is not in an official release yet.  I wonder if your issue is resolved in the 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT.  2.7.0 should be compatible back to 2.5.0 graph implementations so i would expect it to be ok to upgrade.  So, you could either build the console from master or more surgically replace the rexster-protocol-2.y.z.jar with [this one](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/tinkerpop/rexster/rexster-protocol/2.7.0-SNAPSHOT/rexster-protocol-2.7.0-20141124.140611-4.jar) from sonatype.  I'd start with the surgical change first and then if that doesn't work, try to build from source directly.